# Magento 1.7.0.2 : How to redirect home page with specific account

Tags: magento-1.7, home-page, redirect-url

I am kindda new with magento 1, so here is what i don't understand.
In admin, configuration is look like this:
[image]

So what i care about is `Default Web URL` and `CMS Home Page`, So i dont understand about these two, so as far as i know, `CMS Home Page` is just a page which call to a template.
[image]

But what is `Default Web URL` for? That's my side question
Okay, so my main question is `How to  redirect home page with specific account`.
Here is the problem,every NORMAL account after refresh the home page is redirect to `CMS Home Page` as i mentioned before, but for only one account i called "boss", its different, it redirect to a new url, called "boss_url".
Which mean after i refresh the home page, normal account go "example.magento.com" and boss go "example.magento.com/boss_url".

Is there some solution to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Hey In **Default Web URL** you have to pass your **Magento installation** path it basically search for landing page in your magento root.

If you want to redirect a specific account to other page then you need to do some changes in code you can find customer login file here:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
```

In this controller you will find **loginPostAction** Function here you can check that how customer redirect to home page and can edit here to check customer is **Boss** or not if yes then you can redirect that customer to specific page.

I suggest you don't make change in core files you can override this file in your local and then make changes. Hope this help.

if you find this answer useful please mark it as solution or upvote thanks.